# How do I disable the ATI Radeon graphic card during Ubuntu 17.10 installation?

Tags: system-installation, amd-graphics

I am trying to install Ubuntu 17.10 (dual boot with windows 7) in my “HP Pavilion g 6” laptop but it crushes every time because of the “ATI Radeon graphic card”.
Note:

- I already disabled the graphic in windows.
- I can't even open the Terminal.

So how do I disable the ATI Radeon graphic card during installation?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling it in Windows won't affect your linux install.

You should be able to disable it from the BIOS/EFI, thus preventing it from activating during POST.

For instance, if you have a CPU-integrated graphics AND a dedicated graphic card, try disabling the CPU-integrated (it behaves pretty weird on some laptops).
If that doesn't work, disable the PCI graphics and boot with only the CPU stuff (you'll reactivate your PCI card after installing the appropriate driver)

Good luck

Comment: 1- Thank you for answering
2- I can't disable it from Bios
3- i have 2 cards an Intel and AMD and in the past both of them worked fine and I installed Ubuntu for a short time but the AMD turn down and it did not work since then.

Comment: The AMD is probably down because ubuntu can't drive it (normal: no driver).

If I'm not mistaking, your problem is that the Intel chipset is not taking over the AMD when booting on Ubuntu?

I did a quick search and it seems this laptop series comes with a "**switchable graphics settings**" _feature_ that seems to bring more troubles than anything good.

Looks like, that you have to boot Windows, go in the "switchable graphics" section of the Catalyst center and define the Intel chipset as default.

Try also booting on battery (should disable AMD card)

Comment: no, intel work fine, i am using it right know but i will try booting with battery

Comment: No, the battery does not work